# Transmit Power vs. Transmission Power, is there a difference

Tags: writing, science

I was reading a scientific paper, and the authors sometimes use the term **"transmit power"** and sometimes **"transmission power"**.

Is there a difference in terms of correct English usage?

**Examples:**

> we propose to adjust the transmission power used for...

.

> we propose to use transmit power control in order to...

.

> a higher transmit power of a sender should not be...

Comment: They are different words and different parts of speech, and probably used differently because they mean different things.

Comment: I would guess that the terms are not being used with great precision.   But you can ask in the Amateur Radio or Electrical Engineering exchanges to get a more informed opinion,.

Comment: My take is that the first and third are talking about the same thing, while the second is (obviously) talking about a *control* -- a knob or other device that is used to manage the power level.  (I have a masters in electrical engineering, but have never been a "ham" or worked in a broadcast radio/TV studio.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on Electrical Engineering, where it is more likely to receive a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

'Transmission power' would be an amount of power that is being transmitted at the moment, it's a measure of an actual ongoing usage.

'Transmit power control' is the thing that adjusts the level of the power being transmitted, like the volume knob, which can make the sound loud or soft by attenuating the amount power that can be transmitted.

Comment: added one more example

Comment: I still think the distinction they seem to be making is between active/inactive states. 'Transmit' is used when talking about the setting; 'transmission' is used when talking about the power in its flow.

Answer (score 1):

[Both seem to see usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20transmit%20power%2Cthe%20transmission%20power&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20transmit%20power%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20transmission%20power%3B%2Cc0) in noun form. Transmit power is being used as shorthand for transmission power in the examples you gave.

The electrical grid can transmit power to your home. The transmission power of a radio determines the base strength of the signal. Everyone knows what you mean if you replace transmission with transmit, though.